# Transaction API not working in case of Google Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-pay

I am trying to use the sample app for testing the google pay integration: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js

Initially, I got issues for REGION and USER_ACTION_REQUIRED which I solved but now, nothing is happening when trying to pass

```
new TransactionDecision({
 orderOptions: {
    requestDeliveryAddress: false,
  },
 paymentOptions: {
    googleProvidedOptions: {
            prepaidCardDisallowed: false,
            supportedCardNetworks: ['VISA', 'AMEX', 'DISCOVER', 'MASTERCARD'],
            tokenizationParameters: {
        parameters: { "gateway" : "stripe", "stripe:publishableKey" : "pk_live_MYKEY", "stripe:version" : "2019-05-16" } ,
                tokenizationType: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
            },
    },
  },
  proposedOrder: order,
})
```

where order is the object as per the github sample.

When it is calling conv.ask with the above TransactionDecision object, it is failing. I am not getting any error even if the debug level is set to true.

How to proceed further?? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Transaction API as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay).

1. First, do the requirement check.
2. Capture the decision 'silently' using `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION`
3. If transaction available, generate the correct Order object. Tip: start with only required items/parameters for the object.
4. Confirm the user for the order and initiate payment.

This is well documented and explained in the above link.

**Pro Tip:**

- use Google account created for the country you want the transaction API. If the target bot is US-based, make sure your Gmail account was created in the US, with US address. Sometimes, it gives issues if accessing from a country where transaction API is not available.
- use Assistant on mobile for testing as simulator may again give issues.
- on mobile, install fake location app and mock your location to the country where transaction API is supported.